# why use multiple connection strings in asp.net mvc for just one database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, connection-string

I'm using a database which I connected to the project with a conn string. The Asp.Net template gives me also a conn string for the user and identity stuff. So I pointed the conn string to the same database that I need to work with. So, one database will be used for both conn string, the user tables will be generated into the database I already have. 
Is it a good approach to use 2 different conn string in this case, while those 2 are pointing at the same database? Is it better to make just 1 conn string? Or can I choose to do as I want?

Comment: search for [Bounded Context](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html) concept.

Comment: @qbik so in your link, `Product` and `Customer` are same class shared between two context or you have to copies of same named class in different namespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default template will create a `localDB` and the connection string is for that. If you already have SQL Server instance up and running then you can mention that and use that. You don't need the defaults.

BTW, people generally use multiple connection string for different environment like `DEV`, `TEST`, `UAT` etc since they will be having/pointing to different databases.

Comment: I have worked with a friend who keeps the given conn string (for the user) and adds a conn string for its own database, so he works with 2 conn string pointing in the same database, from the same application. I personally deleted the conn string that Asp.Net generates for me, so I worked only with 1 conn string. So I was wondering if I'm doing wrong or if both approaches are ok

Comment: @Arianit, it's a personal opinion/choice but I won't keep two connection string pointing to same DB. For me it may be OK but tomorrow if someone has to work on that app, it may create confusion for him.

Comment: we share the same opinion.. Thanks for your answer and opinion

Comment: this article describse when it is a good situation to use multiple conn strings. http://martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html
But in this case for this project, I'm fine with just 1 conn string

Answer (score 2):

This depends on whether the connection strings are infact semantically the same.  Do they use the same credentials, or other flags which may affect behavior?  You may want fine grained control over which users can access which table.

If instead both strings are semantically equal, it would be best for them to be identical, this way only one connection pool is created (assuming both strings are used in the same app).

Comment: both string are used in the same app, and the user control level will be granted in the application. So if X user wants to access Y table, the application will handle if he has the right for it or not, based on the users role (so I will not work with claims).